# Send an ACTION_SEND intent from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am trying to send and Intent.ACTION_SEND on click of a notification. This is what I have done

```
public static void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message)
{ 
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                        .setContentTitle(title)
                                        .setContentText(message)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
    String extraText = title + " has " + message;
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText);
    PendingIntent pendingShareIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share..."),
                                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share, "share...", pendingShareIntent);

    Notification bigTextNotification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(notificationBuilder)
                                        .setBigContentTitle(title)
                                        .bigText(message)
                                        .build();

    notificationManager.notify(tag, notificationId++, bigTextNotification);
}
```

I get the share action on the notification but when i click it i a dialog box that says

> No Apps can perform this action

When I run the same intent via startActivity() it works fine.

Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to specify a MIME type on the `Intent`, using `setType()`. Try adding that and see if it helps.

Comment: I know I'm hijacking this a little bit but I'm looking for an app or some sort of utility that lets you share downloaded images from the download notification. Imgur's share option in their app only shares a link to the image but I want to embed that image in my Hangouts chat. Currently I have to download the image, open up my file browser, find the oddly named file in a list of other images, select Share from there, select Hangouts, and then hit send. This question seems to be the only thing closely related to what I want on Google. Am I asking the wrong question of Google?